Should we have a tag for all of a specific cryptographer's inventions/contributions?
I came across the merkle tag today. The description says 

Merkle refers to cryptographic advances introduced by Ralph Merkle, like "Merkle's Puzzles", "Merkle's Hash Trees" and the Merkle–Damgård hash function. 

I personally didn't like the idea of having a single tag that refer's to all cryptographic advances/contributions introduced by a specific cryptographer. Should we be doing this? If so, what other tags should we add (Shamir, Rivest, ?)

You might have a small typo up there. The tag is "merkle" while your tag-link says merkel... like the name of Germany's current chancellor. ;)

@e-sushi thanks

As it was me who introduced that tag, it was the least I could do. Speaking of it, I guess you are correct and @paulo-ebermann's answer proposes a good alternative to the current situation (which I caused - sorry).

I don't think the name of a cryptographer is a useful categorization.
That way we would have to add three tags to every RSA question, and two to any Diffie-Hellman question ... what about a question that relates to both?
The three objects (co-)invented/discovered by Ralph Merkle should get individual tags if necessary, like merkle-damgard, merkle-puzzle or merkle-tree.
They don't really have anything in common from a crypto point of view, and I don't suppose that there are people who search for "questions about anything from Merkle" (other than Ralph Merkle himself, maybe).

merkle-damgard probably deserved a tag, but IMO [tree-hash] is enough, we don't need [merkle-tree] in a addition to that.

@CodesInChaos Assuming I've correctly understood you, your reasoning certainly makes sense and that would indeed make tagging easier. So - just to be sure I actually got it right - all tree hashes (eg the Tiger Tree Hash) should go into the [tree-hash] tag? And wouldn't that make "Merkle-Damgård" wrong too according to this reasoning, since that could be generalized using a [hash-function] tag?

I know nobody who makes a distinction between hash-trees and merkle-trees. So these look pretty much like synonyms to me. A Merkle-Damgard tag can be useful when discussing properties of a hash that are specific for this construction, but not when discussing a problem unrelated to MD which just happens to use a hashfunction like MD5 or SHA-2.

For what it's worth, I personally find [merkle-tree] more helpful than [tree-hash].  A "Merkle tree" is a standard term in a cryptography.  A "tree hash" is... well, I wouldn't know what it is, and I don't know if there's any standard accepted meaning for it.  I prefer sticking with Paulo's suggestion (but this is just one vote).

@D.W.: We don't currently have either [tag:tree-hash] or [tag:merkle-tree], but we do have some questions tagged with [tag:hash-tree]. IMO, that's a better name anyway: experts will know it's the same as a Merkle tree, while to non-experts it's more informative. (Surprisingly, there are people interested in crypto who haven't memorized the names of all notable cryptographers yet.) Anyway, a tag synonym from [tag:merkle-tree] to [tag:hash-tree] could be useful, so that someone typing "merkle" into the tag box will get [tag:hash-tree] as a suggestion. Also, it needs a tag wiki...

@IlmariKaronen, good solution!  I like your suggestion.
